ScriptExecution.StreamAccess.Authentication when trying to index data in Azure Ai Studio
Context: I am trying to add my own data to Azure Ai Studio.
I have tried to tweak the access controls and network settings.
For the storage account, I am the owner. I have also given the Azure Ai Studio app and my own user the Reader, Storage Blob Data Reader and Storage Blob Data Contributor access.
I have a virtual network and can only use Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses but I have whitelisted my public ip addresses.

Resource instances wise I have given the workspaces access to storage account.

Inside Azure Ai studio, I have tried to enable authentication via Account Key, SAS. I have also toggled on the Use workspace managed identity for data preview.

I have uploaded the files in a container. I can create new data by connecting to the blob storage. But when indexing the data I get the following error.
Error Code: ScriptExecution.StreamAccess.Authentication
Native Error: error in streaming from input data sources
    StreamError(PermissionDenied(Some(This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)))
=> permission denied when access stream. Reason: Some(This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
    PermissionDenied(Some(This request is not authorized to perform this operation.))
Error Message: Authentication failed when trying to access the stream. Make sure you have correct permissions set up. Ok(This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)| session_id=

Otherwise, when I try to upload a file directly into Azure Ai Studio. I get the following:
The file(s) couldn't be uploaded, because the storage is behind a 
virtual network, the supplied credentials might not have access, or the
storage account permissions might not be set up correctly. If access 
was granted recently, it may take several minutes to update in the 
system - you can simply try again later.

I suspect the issue has something to do with the virtual network but unsure what is the cause. Appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction.

How are you uploading the files: via the portal or a script?

@VenkatV Via the portal

If you select a storage account with a selected network and add a public IP address, accessing the storage account from OpenAI Studio via the portal won't work. To access the storage account, you should be on the same network.

@VenkatV What do you mean by 'on the same network'? How can I achieve that?

The device you are trying to use to access the storage account from OpenAI Studio should be connected to the same network, meaning the same VNet range as the storage account's Crate a Vm with same vnet rage and try to access from vm
